# introduction to xacml implementation

Tags: java, xml, xacml

I wanted to know if anyone could point me in the right direction for novoice who wants to implement xacml.  I have looked at the suns implementation of xacml in java and it is very handy but it does not tell me what i will need e.g what kind of server, configuration and things of that nature. if anyone could help me i would really appreiciate it.  thank you all in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Enterprise XACML](http://code.google.com/p/enterprise-java-xacml/) as it is updated frequenly and still live. The [SunXACML](http://sunxacml.sourceforge.net/) you are talking about is obsolete. You can also take a look at [Axiomatics XACML](http://www.axiomatics.com/pure-xacml.html) implementation, but it is specific implementation of that company.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an open source implementation of XACML 3.0, called "Balana" from here [1]. It is an improvement of sun-xacml which is now obsolete. WSO2 Identity Server which is an open source and enterprise level XACML engine [2]; uses "Balana" as its internal XACML engine. As all sources are available open,  you can go through those sources and see how it has implemented. It would let you to understand things well.  Also you can find more documentation on WSO2 Identity Server's XACML engine from here [3]

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana

[2] http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/

[3] http://xacmlinfo.com/category/xacml/